# Error en import nodejs

Tags: nodejs

Estoy intentando hacer una prueba sencilla con nodejs. Quiero probar este [paquete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-headers) npm pero cuando hago lo que dice en la página me aparece un error. A continuación dejo lo que estoy intentando hacer

```
import { get } from 'http'
import { http } from 'get-headers'

get('http://example.com', (res) => {
  http(res) //=> { 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=604800', 'Content-Type': 'text/html', Date: 'Mon, 17 Aug 2015 19:53:03 GMT', Etag: '"359670651"', Expires: 'Mon, 24 Aug 2015 19:53:03 GMT', 'Last-Modified': 'Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT', Server: 'ECS (rhv/818F)', 'X-Cache': 'HIT', 'x-ec-custom-error': '1', 'Content-Length': '1270', Connection: 'close' }
})
```

El error que me aparece es el siguiente:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { get } from 'http';
                                                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:85:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:266:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:314:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:698:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:749:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:630:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:570:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:801:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11
```

Tengo los dos paquetes instalados en el node_modules, entiendo que es fallo de que no está entiendo bien la última versión de ecmascript y que tendría que hacerlo como toda la vida con el require pero no lo entiendo ya que tengo la última versión de node instalado.

```
node --version                                                           10:43
v11.10.1
```

¿Alguna idea de lo que podría ser?. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Esos imports no son todavía compatibles con Nodejs. Para que funcionase tendrías que usar Babel o Typescript, por ejemplo.

```
import { get } from 'http'
import { http } from 'get-headers'
```

a

```
const get = require('http').get;
const http = require('get-headers').http;
```

No conozco la segunda librería, pero no le encuentro la utilidad. No te olvides de que http es una libería nativa de nodejs, no debes de hacer npm install.